# Django pre_save many_to_many relation

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Category(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)

class Animal(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Animal)
def animal_create_update(sender, **kwargs):
    # get the selected categories and do something
    print(categories)
```

I'm trying to find a way to get access to categories during the pre_save signal. Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
   @receiver(pre_save, sender=Animal)
   def animal_create_update(sender,instance, **kwargs):
       print(instance.categories.all())
```

Let me know

Comment: Thank you Walunas for your response and your time.

I got the following error: 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'

Comment: @Tom I updated my answer. Please not that I added the `instance` to your pre_save receiver

Comment: Thank you once more!

I tried before and just to be sure, tried again now. Got the following error:

`"<Animal: lion>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`

I think the error is related to the pre_save signal (which is a requirement on my application). If I was using post_save would work as you mentioned.

Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe try saving with commit=false, then do your stuff, then save with commit=true. Do u know how to do that?

Comment: No ideia in fact.

Comment: I am thinking about it, and I think you can't do the commit thing there. So let me ask you this. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to call an external api and send the categories names (already created on db) associated to the new animal and the name of the new animal. If the api response is OK, then Im ok to let Django insert on DB, otherwise should return an error message to the user.

Comment: You should be doing this on the view, not on a pre save signal.

Comment: Walucas, you just show me the light. After 1 hour of researching, now everything makes sense! Thank you very very very vey much!! You kinda solve more 3 issues in one comment. Perfect!

Comment: Great to hear it